# MVVM How to put the ListBox SelectedItem into an instance of a class from ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, listbox

I have a problem with the SelectedItem of my ListBox. I want to put my selected item in the Highlighted property of my HealthDiseaseViewModel
Here is my ViewModel:

```
public class HealthDiseaseViewModel : ObservableCollection<HealthDisease>
{
    private string _feedBack;

    HealthDiseaseDb _db = new HealthDiseaseDb();

    public HealthDiseaseRetrieveSingleCommand RetrieveSingleCommand { get; set; }
    public HealthDiseaseRetrieveManyCommand RetrieveManyCommand { get; set; }   
    public HealthDiseaseUpdateCommand UpdateCommand { get; set; }   

    public HealthDisease Entity { get; set; }
    public HealthDisease Highlighted { get; set; }
    public List<HealthDisease> EntityList { get; set; }

    public HealthDiseaseViewModel()
    {
        RetrieveSingleCommand = new HealthDiseaseRetrieveSingleCommand(this);
        RetrieveManyCommand = new HealthDiseaseRetrieveManyCommand(this);       
        UpdateCommand = new HealthDiseaseUpdateCommand(this);       
        Highlighted = new HealthDisease();

        Entity = new HealthDisease();
        RetrieveMany(Entity);
    }

    #region Methods

    public void Retrieve(HealthDisease parameters)
    {
        Highlighted = _db.Retrieve(parameters);            
    }

    public void RetrieveMany(HealthDisease parameters)
    {
        EntityList = new List<HealthDisease>();

        EntityList = _db.RetrieveMany(parameters);      

        IList<HealthDisease> toBeRemoved = Items.ToList();

        foreach (var item in toBeRemoved)
        {
            Remove(item);
        }

        foreach (var item in EntityList)
        {
            Add(item);
        }           
    }

    public void Insert(HealthDisease entity)
    {
        bool doesExist = false;
        if (_db.Insert(entity, SessionHelper.CurrentUser.Id, ref doesExist))
        {
            _feedBack = "Item Successfully Saved!";
            RetrieveMany(new HealthDisease());
        }
        else if (doesExist)
        {
            _feedBack = "Item Already Exists!";
        }
        else
        {
            _feedBack = "Not All Fields Were Filled-In!";
        }
        MessageBox.Show(_feedBack, "Item Insertion");
    }

    public void Update(HealthDisease entity)
    {
        bool doesExist = false;

        if (_db.Update(entity, SessionHelper.CurrentUser.Id, ref doesExist))
        {
            _feedBack = "Item Successfully Updated!";
            RetrieveMany(new HealthDisease());
        }
        else if (doesExist)
        {
            _feedBack = "Item Already Exists!";
        }
        else
        {
            _feedBack = "Not All Fields Were Filled-In!";
        }
        MessageBox.Show(_feedBack, "Item Edition");
    }

    public void Delete(HealthDisease entity)
    {
        var answer = MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Are you sure you want to delete \n{0}?", entity.Name), 
        "Item Deletion", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);

        if (answer == DialogResult.No)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (_db.Delete(entity, SessionHelper.CurrentUser.Id))
        {
            _feedBack = "Item Successfully Deleted!";
            RetrieveMany(new HealthDisease());
        }

        MessageBox.Show(_feedBack, "Item Deletion");
    }   
    #endregion   
}
```

I bound the SelectedItem of my ListBox to Highlighted and I wanted that Highlighted.Name and Highlighted.Description to TextBlocks, but the TextBlocks doesn't show the SelectedItem. I can make a work around here by using SelectedItem.Name and SelectedItem.Description but the problem is it automatically updates the ListBox even if I didn't hit the save button yet. Using the object Highlighted will solve this but I've been spending hours of frustration now.
Here is my markup. I omitted the SaveButton that is bound to UpdateCommand from my ViewModel

```
<Grid Name="MainGrid" Background="Aqua" MinWidth="500" MinHeight="400" 
      DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource HealthViewModel}}">

    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Highlighted.Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBlock>
        <ListBox x:Name="EntityListBox" Margin="10,0" Height="380"
            ItemsSource="{Binding }"
            DisplayMemberPath="Name"
            SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Highlighted, Mode=TwoWay, 
                                   Converter={StaticResource ToHealthDiseaseConverter}, 
                                   UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    </StackPanel>   
</Grid>
```

Comment: your `ItemsSource` of `ListBox` should be a list of HealthDisease.

Comment: but the HealthDiseaseViewModel inherits  ObservableCollection  that has INotifyProp... wouldn't using a list of HealthDisease removes the notification ability?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can provide you a quick answer but kinda hope you won't stop here and trying to find out why binding into an object's property won't work. DependencyProperty bind to instances that implement INotifyPropertyChanged with proper raise PropertyChanged trigger. It don't bind to the "value" of an instance. See if you can figure out why binding to Highlighted.Name won't work.

I created a simplified sample for you

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTestProj.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfTestProj"
    mc:Ignorable="d" 
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=local:MainViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=False}"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=HighlightedName}" />
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel>
            <ListBox x:Name="EntityListBox" Margin="10,0"
                ItemsSource="{Binding EntityList}"
                DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Highlighted, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        </StackPanel>
     </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

```
public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

public class HealthDisease
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<HealthDisease> EntityList { get; set; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        RetrieveMany();
    }

    private void RetrieveMany()
    {
        EntityList = new ObservableCollection<HealthDisease>
        {
            new HealthDisease {Name = "Disease A"},
            new HealthDisease {Name = "Disease B"},
            new HealthDisease {Name = "Disease C"}
        };
    }

    private HealthDisease highlighted;

    public HealthDisease Highlighted
    {
        get { return highlighted; }
        set
        {
            highlighted = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
            OnPropertyChanged("HighlightedName");
        }
    }

    public string HighlightedName
    {
        get { return Highlighted == null ? string.Empty : Highlighted.Name; }
    }
}
```

Comment: GREAT! i also got some shortcut codings from your example. I also didn't know that there can be two OnPropertyChanged()(one with parameters) which updates it in real time.

Comment: Super helpful sample! Small note: your textblock in the XAML can bind directly to `Path=Highlighted.Name` and then you don't need the HighlightedName property in the VM at all. I'm guessing the reason this didn't work in the OP had something to do with how his VM inherits from ObservableCollection (something I've never done) rather than implementing INPC directly, as you did.